# subsetting in Logistic Regression in R

Tags: r, regression

I received the following error messages when splitting and subsetting my data in the process of logistic regression in R:

```
library(caTools) 
split <-sample.split(df1, SplitRatio = 0.5) 
split 
training <- subset(df1, split == "TRUE") 
testing <- subset(df1, split == "FALSE")
```

Error: Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector.
i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
x Input has size 333030 but subscript `i` has size 9.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Questions need to provide reproducible input and code so that anyone else can reproduce the error.  Cut it down to the least data and code needed to exhibit the error. 
 See info at top of [tag:r] tag.

Comment: Here is the code:library(caTools)
split <-sample.split(df1, SplitRatio = 0.5)
split
training <- subset(df1, split == "TRUE")
testing <- subset(df1, split == "FALSE")

Answer (score 0):

The two lines doing the subsetting are one of the problems, although testing is not possible to prove this is the case, since you failed to provide data.. Neither `"TRUE"` nor `"FALSE"` are logical. They are character. This would work if `split` were created correctly (but it obviously wasn't because the lengths of the arguments were not correct:

```
training <- subset(df1, split )   # don't need the `==` if split is logical
testing  <- subset(df1, !split )
```

So the first problem was failing to provide a proper argument for splitting. The length of a dataframe is the number of columns; it's one of the gotcha's of R. However, you need to provide the `sample.split` function just a column vector whose length will then match the number of rows (rather than the number of columns). See the first example in the help page:

```
library(MASS)
  data(cats)   # load cats data
  Y = cats[,1] # extract labels from the data, just one column needed
  msk = sample.split(Y, SplitRatio=3/4)
  str(msk)
  # logi [1:144] TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE ...
```

A couple of other pointers. It's a bad idea to name the logical vector `split` because there is a base R function named `split`. And you should not use comments for code. They don't come across properly formatted. Use SO's edit facilities that you can access with the links below youyr question body: [image]